# I'm trying to get days between the two dates but it's not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get days between the two dates from two columns then add the value to the new column. There are 97013 rows.

```
from datetime import datetime


def days_between(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(str(d1), "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(str(d2), "%Y-%m-%d")
    return abs((d2-d1).days)

for x, y, z in zip(order_time.loc[:,'date_order'], order_time.loc[:,'date_delivered'],
                  order_time.loc[:, 'diff']):
    z = days_between(x, y)
```

However, I got the same values returned throughout the entire column in the column 'diff'.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
order_time['days_between'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(order_time['date_delivered']) -
    pd.to_datetime(order_time['date_order'])
).apply(lambda x: x.days)
```